# How to correctly inherit from str?

Tags: python, inheritance, unicode, built-in

sqlobject version that I'm forced to use expects magic `__unicode__` on custom string-like types, I'm trying to inherit form string and satisfy that requirement:

```
class Foo(str):
    extra_attribute = 42

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self)  # optional

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self)  # infinite recursion
        return super(Foo, self).__unicode__()  # str doesn't have __unicode__
        return unicode(str(self))  # an ugly hack, but works
```

Is the last line the best I can do, or is there a cleaner way?

Apparently proper way to convert unicode-like objects in Python 2.x is this:

```
return unicode(x)
```

Or, more verbosely:

```
if hasattr(x, "__unicode__"):
    return x.__unicode__()
else:
    return unicode(x)
```

Unfortunately, sqlobject version that I have to use doesn't do that.

Comment: The proper way is to *decode* to Unicode. `self.decode(some_encoding)`.

Comment: Does `sqlobject` *enforce* subclassing `str`? I think subclassing built-ins is something that should be avoided as much as possible.

Comment: In fact, *subclassing* should be avoided as it introduces tight coupling. Duck typing is the way to avoid that.

Comment: @larsmans good point. here I did it for convenience.

Comment: @Bakuriu not really, I was stuck with old version of sqlobject that placed tight requirements on string-like objects. Newer sqlobject is better, though admittedly not perfect yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way is to *decode* to Unicode. `self.decode(some_encoding)`.

Byte strings can be any encoding. If you *always* use ASCII, then use that as your codec:

```
return self.decode('ASCII')
```

Comment: I've seen others prefer `unicode(...)` builtin/constructor over `str.decode(...)`, what's your take on that?

Comment: If they omit a codec, then they have not thought through what it means to convert from a bytestring to a unicode value. *With* a codec, I have no preference. `unicode(...)` might be a little faster as it is a direct built-in call vs. a method lookup plus call.